# How to add differrent color Scheme for two chart using angular chart JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I am using angular chart JS for Doughnut Chart and Line Chart. Want to be different color for both not same color scheme.
As Showing in the Image:
[In image there is two different chart with different color. I need like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8K69.jpg)

Comment: Can you share what yo’ve tried so far? Please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You set the colors in:

```
ChartJsProvider.setOptions({
  colours: ['#FF5252', '#FF8A80'],
  responsive: false
});
```

Check in the [Documentation](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js)

I see you use the US English "color"

> Want to be different color for both not same **color** scheme.

It looks like they use UK English in the API **`colours:`**. Might lead to confusion

Comment: Please see the edit, I need different color for two chart